# Back of stove looks burnt

Tags: wiring, oven

I just had to replace the bake element for my GE oven. While doing so I noticed the back of the oven looks like it is burnt. Is this ok?[image]

Comment: The insulation did its job and did not catch fire. But you need to determine why this happened. You need to inspect the wires and teminals to see if they are burned, melted or missing their insulated covering.

Comment: The ground wire insulation looks charred too. how about a picture of the old element terminals?  Can you tell where that white wire goes?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the insulation is intact I have seen much worse. I would leave it as is even the ground. If you do need to change any of the spade / disconnect fittings make sure to get high temp ones, standard female connectors like mni10-250dfix  will not hold up well to the heat, with the thermal cycling they become loose and will burn the end off. I learned this years ago after repairing an oven and the new ends did not last long, I use high temp (900 deg) ends like FR9C-250.
What you have there looks ok to me and is quite normal at when element entrance area so I would say it is ok.